# How to create sending application in HL7 message end with double caret(^) via nHapi?

Tags: hl7, nhapi

How can I create sending facility(ABCSite^^) in MSH segment as below?

```
MSH|^~\&|AbcSite^^|XYZFacility|||201506211402||OMI^O23|20150621140223834684|D^T|2.4
```

Comment: Please add a few examples of things you tried, this will usually elicit a better response from the community. You can always update your question. Welcome to stack overflow, recommended reading: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do that. Trailing component separators at the end of a field serve no purpose and should be removed to save space. You don't want to add extra ones.

Comment: I totally agree with you. But stakeholder of one HL7 peer created such strict specification. I could add some special string, and replace it with double carets before send out.